# Python ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'src' Process completed with exit code 1

Tags: python, modulenotfounderror

I am getting error ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'src' while running it on github action.

[[image: My file structure is]]

```
unnittest.yml

name : test

on: workflow_dispatch

jobs:
  build:
    steps:
      - name: checkout repo content
        uses: actions/checkout@v3 
      - name: Install Python Dependencies
        run: |
          python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip
          pip install pytest
        shell: bash
      - name: Run test
        run: |
          python3 ./tests/t1.py
```

```
ad.py

def area(a):
  return a*a

def main():
  
  ans = area(5)
  print(ans)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

```
t1.py

import unittest 
from unittest import mock
from src import ad as ad

class Test_ad(unittest.TestCase):

   def test_area(self):
       assert ad.area(5) == 25


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

I do not understand the error ! can any one assist me?
Thank you !